# Почему вылетает ошибка при инициализации tasr gulp?

Tags: gulp, npm

Здравствуйте. При установке зависимостей через npm i вылетает ошибка (дважды)

Дальше установка проходит, но уже сборка проекта проходит некорректно. Как побороть эту ошибку?

```
E:\Projects\frontend\node_modules\posix\node_modules\nan\nan.h(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node_version.h': No such file or directory (compiling
 source file ..\src\posix.cc) [E:\Projects\frontend\node_modules\posix\build\posix.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:285:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\Projects\frontend\node_modules\posix
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]